# EditText visibility

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I have code:

```
...
        final EditText edit_1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edit_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final EditText edit_2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        edit_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
...
        btn_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (edit_1.getText().toString() == "1")
                {
                    edit_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

On default, first EditText is visible and second one - invisible. I want to set second editor visible after button pressing, if in the first editor typed "1". It doesn't work, What is wrong?

Comment: By "it doesn't work", what do you mean? Do you get an error, does edit_2 stay invisible? Explain more.

Comment: Is it something to do with the comparison, are you sure you are comparing a string and a string ("1") or string and integer (1) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare two string the == operand doesn't works, you need to use `equals()` method.

Inside `OnClick()` you need something like this:

```
if (edit_1.getText().equals("1"))
{
       edit_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
//***IN ONCLICK LISTENER***//
String text = edit_1.getText().toString();
        if (text.equals("1")) { 
    edit_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
```